# PHP mysqli prepared UPDATE statement fails

Tags: php, mysqli

I am calling this function from another page, but it gives me the below error:
Warning: mysqli::prepare(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in

```
public function ResetTalentCandidate() {
    // Get global vars
    global $conn;
    global $authUserId;

    // Get post data
    $candidateID = $_REQUEST['resetID'];
    $statusUpdate = 0;
    $dateReset = time();

    if ($stmt = $conn->prepare ("UPDATE `rf_opportunitypool` SET pool_status = ? WHERE candidate_id = $candidateID;") or die (mysqli_error($conn))) {
        // Bind values
        $stmt->bind_param ('ii', $authUserId, $dateReset);

        // Execute query
        $stmt->execute();

        // Close statment
        $stmt->close();

        // Successfully updated
        return true;
    }

    // Nothing happened
    return false;
}
```

I have similar functions elsewhere in my class but don't have the same problem. Could I be missing something somewhere?

Comment: You have 1 placeholder and you bind 2 parameters

Comment: Sorry, I actually had 3 placeholders, which I removed during testing. The problem is actually with the prepare statement and not the bind parameters.

Comment: Are you 100% confident about the content of $candidateID ? Can you show the actual string passed to prepare?

Comment: So the original prepare is:    if ($stmt = $conn->prepare ("UPDATE `rf_opportunitypool` SET `pool_status` = 0, `pool_change_by` = ?, `pool_change_date` = ? WHERE candidate_id = $candidateID;") or die (mysqli_error($conn))) {
            // Bind values
            $stmt->bind_param ('iii', $authUserId, $dateReset);
   
            // Execute query
            $stmt->execute();
   
            // Close statment
            $stmt->close();
   
            // Successfully updated
            return true;
  }

Comment: The content of $candidateID is an int like 5712032

Comment: It seems you are not getting `$conn`, so the error is coming

Comment: Will investigate $conn then

Comment: It turns out Harshit Shrivastava was correct. The $conn object was the issue. So DatabaseDisconnect () was being called somewhere in the system by another file before my method. So I just had to call it before this  file and all is good now. Thanks for the assistance everyone.